# How do i get python to remove the row i search for from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am able to edit and add new entries but everytime i try to delete the row i search for, it wipes the whole files data.

**I need it to just remove that row of data without losing the rest of the rows.**

```
    import csv,os,sys

def helper(file):
    o=csv.reader(open(file,"r"))
    for row in o:
        print row

def delete(filename):
    found=False
    f1=csv.reader(open(filename,'r'))
    f2=csv.writer(open("temp.csv",'a'))
    rid=raw_input("Enter name to find record:")
    for row in f1:
        if rid in row[0]:
            found=True
            f2.writerow()
            print rid, "has been deleted from the database!"
        else:
            found=False
    if found==False:
        print "That name isn't in our database!"
        z=raw_input("Please enter 1 to retry, 2 to return to log in, or 3 to close program:")
        if z=="1":
            delete(filename)
        if z=="2":
            import program
        if z=="3":
            exit




helping=raw_input("Do you require any help with using this feature?Type y for yes or just hit enter to continue:")
if helping=="y":
    helper('deletehelp.txt')

delete("custdet.csv")       
os.remove("custdet.csv")
os.rename("temp.csv","custdet.csv")     #This is the file rename that I mentioned above.
restart=raw_input("Would you like to return to the main menu? Please type Y or just hit enter to exit:")
if restart=="y":
    import program
else: exit
```

Comment: maybe your f2.writerow() is supposed to be outside the if statement!!! And yes, its empty as well.

Comment: could you show me what you mean?

Comment: if you want to delete the row,that user enters, you surely dont want to write it to your new file! so it should be outside the __if__ block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv,os,sys

def helper(file):
    o = csv.reader(open(file,"r"))
    for row in o:
        print row

def delete(filename):
    f1 = csv.reader(open(filename,'r'))
    f2 = csv.writer(open("temp.csv",'a'))
    rid = raw_input("Enter name to find record:")
    found = False
    for row in f1:
        if rid not in row[0]:
            f2.writerow(row)
        else:
            found = True
            print rid, "has been deleted from the database!"

    if found == False:
        print "That name isn't in our database!"
        z = raw_input("Please enter 1 to retry, 2 to return to log in, or 3 to close program:")
        if z == "1":
            delete(filename)
        if z == "2":
            import program
        if z == "3":
            exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You never actually write to the new csv file.

Look at the main filter/copy loop:

```
# for every row in the input file
for row in f1:
        # Is this the/a record to delete?
        if rid in row[0]:
            # yes!
            found=True
            # then we do not write anything to the output file (???)
            f2.writerow()
            print rid, "has been deleted from the database!"
        # no else part, so no nothing gets done with
        # the input row `row` ...
```

So you'll end up with an empty output file ...

Answer (score 0):

Change the section containing the for loop to this:

```
    for row in f1:
        if rid in row[0]:
            found=True
            print rid, "has been deleted from the database!"
        else:
            f2.writerow(row)
```

The changes:

- Actually write the row if `rid` is not in `row[0]`
- Don't reset the `found` flag to `False`

The rest of the code also needs some work:

- Recursion is not the best way to handle retries, use a loop instead.
- `import program` to return to the login ????? That's not going to
  work. Perhaps you should just return from the function.
- There is coupling between `delete()` and the calling code which
  relies on a file named `temp.csv` being created. It would be much
  better if `delete()` performed the renaming of the temporary file itself.